# Find Elliptic Curve Parameters, a and b, Given Two Points on the Curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am new to Elliptic Curve Cryptography and am working on a CTF challenge that uses Elliptic Curves. Currently, I am trying to find the generator, $G$, and am given the public and private keys, $P$ and $k$, s.t. $P = [k]G$, as well as one other random point on the curve. I know the order, $n$, of the group, and I know the two prime numbers, $p$ and $q$, which are the sole factors of $n$.

I [read](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/86663/how-to-find-the-base-point-given-public-and-private-key-and-ec-parameters-except) that if you have the private and public keys, you can compute the generator as ...

$$G = [k^{-1}]P\pmod n$$

... where $k^{-1} = n - k$.

That's all great, but, unfortunately, I do not know the parameters, $a$ and $b$, of the elliptic curve, $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$, and so I'm having trouble performing EC point multiplication by $k^{-1}$.

I was thinking, since I know the values of two points on the curve, I essentially have the following system of linear equations:

\begin{align}
y_1^2 &= x_1^3 + ax_1 + b\\
y_2^2 &= x_2^3 + ax_2 + b\\
\end{align}

I tried solving this using the z3 theorem solver but was given an answer, asserting that the system is unsatisfiable. I then tried modifying my system of equations so that both sides of the equation are calculated modulo $n$, but this resulted in z3 taking forever to find the solution, presumably because $a$ and $b$ are 128-bit numbers and $n$ is a 512-bit number. This got me thinking back to my undergraduate computer science classes, where I remember learning about various problems in computer science, and this seems similar to [Integer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming), which is NP-complete.

Therefore, is it possible to efficiently compute the parameters, $a$ and $b$, of an elliptic curve if I know the order $n$ and two points $P$ and $Q$ on the curve?

Comment: To invert $k$ to get $k^{-1}$, you need to do a "modulo multiplicative inverse". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given two points on the curve $P=(x_1,y_1), Q=(x_2,y_2)$ we can determine the parameters of the short Weierstrass form $y^2 = x^2 + ax +b$. Insert the coordinates of the points to the curve equation to get two equations as you did;

\begin{align}
y_1^2 &= x_1^3 + ax_1 + b &\pmod{n} \\
y_2^2 &= x_2^3 + ax_2 + b &\pmod{n}\\ \hline & & \text{subtract}\\
y_1^2 - y_2^2 &= x_1^3 - x_2^3 + a (x_1 - x_2) &\pmod{n}\\
(y_1^2 - y_2^2) -(x_1^3 - x_2^3)&=  a (x_1 - x_2) &\pmod{n}\\
[(y_1^2 - y_2^2) -(x_1^3 - x_2^3)] \cdot (x_1 - x_2)^{-1}&=  a &\pmod{n}\\
\end{align}

To be able to find $a$, the only problem is the existence of the [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $(x_1 - x_2)$ to the $\bmod n$.

- If $\gcd((x_1 - x_2),n) = 1$ then the modular multiplicative inverse is exist and can be easily found with [Extended Euclidean algorithm (Ext-GCD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)
- If $\gcd((x_1 - x_2),n) \neq 1$ then there is no inverse (see What if below).
- Note that, in the case $x_1 - x_2 = 0$ then we have $\gcd(0,n) = n.$ In other words, there is no inverse.

Once $a$ is successfully found, finding $b$ is easier. Plug the known $a$ into the equation then solve it for the only unknown $b$.

---

SageMath for the modular inverse;

```
Zn = Integers(12)
a = Zn(5)
b = a^-1
a
```

if one sets $a = 4$ then they will get the error: `ZeroDivisionError: inverse of Mod(4, 12) does not exist`.

---

**What if** There is no inverse of $(x_1 - x_2)$ to $\bmod{n}$. Can we find solution(s) to below?

$$(y_1^2 - y_2^2) -(x_1^3 - x_2^3)=  a (x_1 - x_2) \pmod{n} \label{a}\tag{1}$$

Yes, we can still find solutions to $\ref{a}$ but they will not be unique.

> **Lemma:** If $d$ is the greatest common divisor of a and m then the linear congruence $ax \equiv b \pmod m$ has solutions if and only if $d$ divides $b$. If $d$ divides $b$, then there are exactly $d$ solutions

To find them, form $a/d \cdot x \equiv b/d \pmod{m/d}$. It is clear that $\gcd(a/d,m/d)=1$. Then we can invert $a/d$ and solve for $x$. Then $\{x, x+\dfrac{m}{d},x+\dfrac{2m}{d}, \ldots, x+\dfrac{(d-1)m}{d} \}$ are the $d$ solutions for  equation $\ref{a}$.

For each of the solutions, it is expected to have a different $b$, therefore for uniquely determine additional information will be needed.

Comment: The equation $ab = c (\text{mod} n)$ can hold even if neither a nor b has a multiplicative inverse. Shouldn't the correct condition be whether $(y_1^2 - y_2^2) - (x_1^3 - x_2^3)$ divides $\gcd(x_1 - x_2, n)$?

Comment: @2.71828-asy Take the case $4x \equiv 6 \bmod 10$, $4x = 6 + 10 k$ divide by 2, we have $2x = 3 \bmod 5$ so $x = 4$ and the other one is $x+5$ since both satisfies $4x \equiv 6 \bmod 10$ they are both solutions. The inverse, however, must be unique!

Comment: Ok, so since we know there must be a unique $a$, we know that we are looking for an inverse and not a solution?

Comment: @2.71828-asy while answering in the first case, I was considering this case, too. However, I did not think that the OP will need that so concentrated on the unique solution. Added a part for that. In a second look, I've seen that they may need. Added as **What if**, thanks. This is a very common problem in Hill cipher solutions that we propose to look...

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks! Your explanation helped me realize my mistake. I was doing regular division by $(x_1 - x_2)$ rather than modular division.

Comment: @jinscoe123 ECC is a bit complex since there is a field than the coordinates are forming a group under addition law. However, every operation is done to the base field. I've put the Sagemath to note that one needs special command to let $a \in \mathbb Z_5$ or handle yourself in other programming languages.